# Microsoft Dynamics crm filter by accountid and name in contact via api

Tags: php, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Trying to filter all the contact under particular accountid. Need to have name filter also.

```
url:
https://alliedmodulartemp.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/contacts?$filter=contains(first_name,'anhu')
Method:GET
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below url should work.

```
https://alliedmodulartemp.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/contacts?$filter=contains(firstname, 'anhu') and  _parentcustomerid_value eq A6618972-2AFA-E911-A813-000D3A4AAC87
```